# PHP or CURL ASPX.NET Login

Tags: php, asp.net, .net, post, curl

After hours of trying.. I'm attempting to Login to ASPX and retrieve a certain page.

Here is post data

```
POST /xdesktopdefault.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fxPostings.aspx%3fbaseid%3d5%26postingid%3d28217%26Type%3dViewPost&baseid=5&postingid=28217&Type=ViewPost HTTP/1.1
Host: my.dotstaff.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
X-MicrosoftAjax: Delta=true
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Referer: https://my.dotstaff.com/xdesktopdefault.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fxPostings.aspx%3fbaseid%3d5%26postingid%3d28217%26Type%3dViewPost&baseid=5&postingid=28217&Type=ViewPost
Content-Length: 1228
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
=rapLoginPanel%7CbtnLogin&__LASTFOCUS=&rsmLogin_TSM=%3B%3BSystem.Web.Extensions%2C%20Version%3D4.0.0.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3D31bf3856ad364e35%3Aen-US%3Ae71d0a15-7471-4384-9905-78bdf2047cba%3Aea597d4b%3Ab25378d2%3BTelerik.Web.UI%2C%20Version%3D2011.1.413.35%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3D121fae78165ba3d4%3Aen-US%3Abd09f19b-b595-4ea4-8ab8-449a745bc83c%3A16e4e7cd%3Af7645509%3A24ee1bba%3Af46195d3%3A19620875%3A874f8ea2%3A490a9d4e%3Abd8f85e4%3A86526ba7%3Aed16cbdc&__EVENTTARGET=btnLogin&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUKMTk4NDgxMTcyNxBkZBYCAgMPZBYIAgMPFCsAAhQrAAMPFgIeF0VuYWJsZUFqYXhTa2luUmVuZGVyaW5naGRkZGRkAgUPDxYCHwBoFgIeBXN0eWxlBQ1kaXNwbGF5Om5vbmU7ZAIHDw8WAh8AaGRkAgkPZBYMAgEPZBYCAg0PDxYCHhFVc2VTdWJtaXRCZWhhdmlvcmhkZAIDD2QWBAIJDw8WAh8CaGRkAgsPDxYCHwJoZGQCBQ9kFgQCCQ8PFgIfAmhkZAILDw8WAh8CaGRkAgcPZBYCAk8PDxYCHwJoZGQCCQ8PFgIeBFRleHQFF3YwMDYtMDAxLTAwMy0wMTMtMDEyLXMzZGQCCw8PFgIfAwUIwqkgMjAxNCBkZBgBBR5fX0NvbnRyb2xzUmVxdWlyZVBvc3RCYWNrS2V5X18WAgUIcnduTG9naW4FCHJmZExvZ2luzcBWU%2BKUMp4PaiTQDZMHpon%2Bi9M6qemtrhWQtvk2mis%3D&rwnLogin_ClientState=&rfdLogin_ClientState=&txtAccount={EMAILADDRESS}&txtPassword={PASSWORD}&__ASYNCPOST=true&RadAJAXControlID=rapLogin
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 3835
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=5pbupfmzyp1mpefleyzgcxmx; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=C51253CE9E8F384F25D49C8F8DC234FAFF262D8F69762E7640DAE6956DE5ED1FA776B19E13A3B94E3C94DDBAEA29EAE22A5ECFE091B042A9615A70F8BC9669A87546B820286992A45421FB23FF7B2FB77B169A15175B891DB1A15A7BFD57607D125E017CF210542F0045386BF1D9B598CA87EED469B718956A05236DF290C5ACAC0AC05DB3745AAAE5840DA6CA3936442D672FE1F2B45671BBE5F6B027D203B444932CE62323D640023C1F49E11C1FEDC21C7359F691569C6C37E0CACAB556E5; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

I've scrapped all of my attempts using php and curl I'm either getting page redirects or cannot get past the login screen with problems with cookies & certs - I figured I was totally off base could anyone provide some guidance?

These are my Request / Response Headers
Request headers

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36
Origin: chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
Accept: */*
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=valvpqjtkvsq5iti1bn0yl0q; .ASPXAUTH=24623412C011F3D4BD5A6BC513CF52FBD402382A7A43CB368476FC3A84B12C46718DA730311A7481C86EDCF7B95693FC7AC6A0B2D1D3DD4903CBF2215FB4C50345F1A7CC857BF7EB231B342550F828A33B42B9EBDCC908CB2DB27961E5BD45C8C2F0FC75EA55D59DB96D1D14D67DBE60D9068D118656E5A2198A536974878980EA91275F981C47C0868BBA5C6694F8A542D41066A70FCADCD7D92794EB3A8D208DF2F8C79F8D6EB1F36580A08A1ED0013604662FC938659D46C522D47E524056; __utma=204864268.1222118243.1395925849.1395925849.1395930021.2; __utmb=204864268.1.10.1395930021; __utmc=204864268; __utmz=204864268.1395925849.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); WT_FPC=id=2dcd2aecfa02174e22e1395940248104:lv=1395944421673:ss=1395944421655; userroles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
```

Response headers

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store 
Pragma: no-cache 
Transfer-Encoding: chunked 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 
Content-Encoding: gzip 
Expires: -1 
Vary: Accept-Encoding 
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: userroles=6005ACAD5D4E8FE697CFC21EE4269632FDC0DBA706B39DF29BDC73EB4D46A66F115BB19E86FFE884867CC1171EFD8ED3AAFE7A29106E5EE87700339090304569056AB35A813E8303DD31B952063F0B25F4FA1A692E06E4D5F5F1C1774513EE15583D84CE34E62598FEA09707D4BCDFEBF6D2D32141B49202C056FBFB192840BAB2F6D46805B02A282A924071B9D933962792B4AA1F0AB1B6A1EAD06F3EDC0AE42124F7BA8C7DCB2442C51546F05BD0B6DEED64A67D7EDF2EC20280C39B076DC853DB26ACE3AE82AED64387C6AC4B754A0C89E93938ED9E483B1C46FA6DC2BFD5E7A13B8BE55403CA04C6CD9F0F57D46621EFE413C814C5204589A01CC79F388F466F4D1C1BF617F0171FB272DD0A1B9D73F95FB644895E7DD254B0030E5264FBCF2FCC4AAA86892E5835A267E795A1BFC59B892BEB71E8887DC54D41F99E5FA34EA91634F57E2D1E7AC370324D592FC150BF97E77E99589D0712E62D9B509CD4A84D20F3EEB902F086D8AA28E6E0A0345D786979CA7E91724787A7C59775EDF52AFC71B3BC44242DFE42BE1D9AF9A1F27DCC095CD99BA22C9BE9307C8343768A21DED2E5BA493B4CF48B08B2049C66DD4BDACEB836BA75916D1F5E6C19869971; expires=Thu, 27-Mar-2014 15:23:38 GMT; path=/ 
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 27 Mar 2014 14:23:39 GMT
```

Is there something I'm supposed to do to find the auth method?

```
<form method="post" action="xdesktopdefault.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fxPostings.aspx%3fbaseid%3d5%26postingid%3d27717%26Type%3dViewPost&amp;baseid=5&amp;postingid=27717&amp;Type=ViewPost" id="form1">
    <div class="aspNetHidden">
        <input type="hidden" name="__LASTFOCUS" id="__LASTFOCUS" value=""/>
        <input type="hidden" name="rsmLogin_TSM" id="rsmLogin_TSM" value=""/>
        <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value=""/>
        <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value=""/>
        <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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"/>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
    </script>
    <script src="/WebResource.axd?d=lmkRxd3K_LfpwuJWavWbR9O8oVpO_3HzVQYSafNqInZH2LmiRcbPQU4TK4VbGEjriAL7MKIAwKJeZGe2tIvUhCaAdIM-QNE3NpgeC1FSooU1&amp;t=634514284903485726" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=rsmLogin_TSM&amp;compress=1&amp;_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3ae71d0a15-7471-4384-9905-78bdf2047cba%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%2c+Version%3d2011.1.413.35%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d121fae78165ba3d4%3aen-US%3abd09f19b-b595-4ea4-8ab8-449a745bc83c%3a16e4e7cd%3af7645509%3a24ee1bba%3af46195d3%3a19620875%3a874f8ea2%3a490a9d4e%3abd8f85e4%3a86526ba7%3aed16cbdc" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/WebResource.axd?d=-W1mbMluT4BbqRckfWlNJav-vGM--AKM8HPzfcRDsN_-FgqnLCY-jiKJymsml63_hw2PWqDIx5WKYtLGxA-Yrz9rHeVJOdtTWEuOTqc98Dk1&amp;t=634514284903485726" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('rsmLogin', 'form1', ['trapLoginPanel','rapLoginPanel'], [], [], 90, '');
//]]>
    </script>
    <div id="rwnLogin" style="display:none;">
        <!-- 2011.1.413.35 -->
        <div id="rwnLogin_alerttemplate" style="display:none;">
            <div class="rwDialogPopup radalert">
                <div class="rwDialogText">
                     {1}
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a onclick="$find('{0}').close(true);" class="rwPopupButton" href="javascript:void(0);">
                    <span class="rwOuterSpan">
                    <span class="rwInnerSpan">##LOC[OK]##</span>
                    </span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="rwnLogin_prompttemplate" style="display:none;">
            <div class="rwDialogPopup radprompt">
                <div class="rwDialogText">
                     {1}
                </div>
                <div>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    function RadWindowprompt_detectenter(id, ev, input)
                    {                           
                        if (!ev) ev = window.event;                
                        if (ev.keyCode == 13)
                        {                                                                   
                            var but = input.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("A")[0];                         
                            if (but)
                            {                           
                                if (but.click) but.click();
                                else if (but.onclick)
                                {
                                    but.focus(); var click = but.onclick; but.onclick = null; if (click) click.call(but);                            
                                }
                            }
                           return false;
                        } 
                        else return true;
                    }    
                    </script>
                    <input title="Enter Value" onkeydown="return RadWindowprompt_detectenter('{0}', event, this);" type="text" class="rwDialogInput" value="{2}"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a onclick="$find('{0}').close(this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value);" class="rwPopupButton" href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="rwOuterSpan"><span class="rwInnerSpan">##LOC[OK]##</span></span></a>
                    <a onclick="$find('{0}').close(null);" class="rwPopupButton" href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="rwOuterSpan"><span class="rwInnerSpan">##LOC[Cancel]##</span></span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="rwnLogin_confirmtemplate" style="display:none;">
            <div class="rwDialogPopup radconfirm">
                <div class="rwDialogText">
                     {1}
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a onclick="$find('{0}').close(true);" class="rwPopupButton" href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="rwOuterSpan"><span class="rwInnerSpan">##LOC[OK]##</span></span></a>
                    <a onclick="$find('{0}').close(false);" class="rwPopupButton" href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="rwOuterSpan"><span class="rwInnerSpan">##LOC[Cancel]##</span></span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input id="rwnLogin_ClientState" name="rwnLogin_ClientState" type="hidden"/>
    </div>
    <div id="rfdLogin" style="display:none;">
        <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
if (typeof(WebForm_AutoFocus) != 'undefined')
{
    var old_WebForm_AutoFocus = WebForm_AutoFocus;
    WebForm_AutoFocus = function(arg)
    {
        Sys.Application.add_load(function()
        {
            old_WebForm_AutoFocus(arg);
            WebForm_AutoFocus = old_WebForm_AutoFocus;
        });
    }
}
if (typeof(Telerik) != 'undefined')
{
    if (Telerik.Web.UI.RadFormDecorator)
    {
        Telerik.Web.UI.RadFormDecorator.initializePage("rfdLogin", "", "WebBlue", 65535);
    }
}
//]]>
        </script>
        <input id="rfdLogin_ClientState" name="rfdLogin_ClientState" type="hidden"/>
    </div>
    <div id="rlpLoading" class="RadAjax RadAjax_WebBlue" style="display:none;width:75px;">
        <div class="raDiv">
        </div>
        <div class="raColor raTransp">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="rapLoginPanel">
        <div id="rapLogin">
            <div id="container">
                <div id="pnlLogin" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, &#39;btnLogin&#39;)">
                    <div id="marketing-background">
                        <div id="marketing-content">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="login">
                        <div id="login-controls">
                            <span id="Label1">Login Email:</span><br/>
                            <input name="txtAccount" type="text" id="txtAccount" tabindex="1" style="width:200px;"/>
                            <a id="lnkActivate" tabindex="4" class="lnkActivate" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;lnkActivate&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">Activate Account</a>
                            <br/>
                            <br/>
                            <span id="Label2">Password:</span><br/>
                            <input name="txtPassword" type="password" id="txtPassword" tabindex="2" oncopy="return false" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" style="width:200px;"/>
                            <a id="lnkResetPassword" tabindex="5" class="lnkActivate" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;lnkResetPassword&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">Reset Password</a>
                            <br/>
                            <br/>
                            <div class="btnLogin">
                                <input type="button" name="btnLogin" value="Login" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;btnLogin&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))" id="btnLogin" tabindex="3" class="button-style"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="notify-background">
                        <div id="notify-content">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: An ASPX page is just HTML from the client perspective. What kind of authentication? Basic, Forms, or Integrated Windows Authentication?

Comment: Is there something I'm supposed to do to find the auth method?

Comment: Yeah, familiar yourself with the authentication methods, then see which one they're using.

Comment: It is utilizing form auth method. Posts form to server server responds with gzip file.